# sns stripplot with just top n number of categories

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-visualization, seaborn

I have code that plots sns stripplot nicely :

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,12))
sns.stripplot(data = cars, x='price', y='model', jitter=.5)
plt.show()
```

but there are too many car models so I wish to visualize only top n most frequently appearing car models in dataset.
Also is there any lambda calculations or something similar that I can apply to `price` or `model` without creating separate data frame?

If there is better visualization library that can help with that feel free to propose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the most occurring values of a column with [value_counts()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html). Here I've selected the top 2 most occurring models:

```
most_occurring_values = cars['model'].value_counts().head(2).index
```

Then you could filter your original dataframe and only select rows that contain the models with the highest frequency:

```
cars_subset = cars[cars['model'].isin(most_occurring_values)]
```

Finally, use that subset to plot your data:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,12))
sns.stripplot(data = cars_subset, x='price', y='model', jitter=.5)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I am aware I can do it like that, but I was thinking if there is method which I can pass to sns that can filter data frame and work upon it without creating separate data frame.

Answer (score 0):

According to [official documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.stripplot.html)

> **order, hue_order** : *lists of strings, optional. Order to plot the categorical levels in, otherwise the levels are inferred from the data
>   objects.*

To select the top 3 models, you can do:

```
sns.stripplot(data = cars, x='price', y='model', jitter=.5, order=cars.model.value_counts().iloc[:3].index)
```